# Django/Celery: celeryd won't retrieve new tasks from queue unless restarted

Tags: django, celery

I cannot figure out why `celeryd` is not pulling new tasks that are added to the queue.  It will only retrieve tasks once it is started, then fails to monitor thereafter.  I am running the Django development server with django-celery using the Django ORM for the message broker.

My Django settings file has this configuration for celery:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ("djcelery", )
INSTALLED_APPS += ("djkombu", )

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_TRANSPORT = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"

BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"

BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"
```

Furthermore if it matters, I am using a *remote* MySQL server as my database backend.

**Edit:  Resolved!**

After spending several hours on this, I found an answer in the Celery FAQ:

[MySQL is throwing deadlock errors, what can I do?](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#mysql-is-throwing-deadlock-errors-what-can-i-do)

I wasn't seeing the deadlock errors in the log, but modifying my `/etc/my.cnf` to include:

```
[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

resolved my issue.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending several hours on this, I found an answer in the Celery FAQ:

> [MySQL is throwing deadlock errors, what can I do?](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#mysql-is-throwing-deadlock-errors-what-can-i-do)

I wasn't seeing the deadlock errors in the log, but modifying my /etc/my.cnf to include:

[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED

resolved my issue.

Hope this helps someone else!